# Is there a good base for me to work from for php user registration + subscription in MVC format?

Tags: php, zend-framework, paypal, subscription

Basically, I'm about to write a php script in the Zend Framework that's ONLY purpose is to handle user registration and offer AUTOMATIC MONTHLY subscriptions so that I can add other php driven scrips that they'll have access to based on their subscription status.

Does something already do this? I'm looking for barebones, not something like zencart or ecommerce software that does 10000 things. User registration and subscriptions only.

I want to use this as a base to offer other php driven tools that would require a subscription to access.

Comment: Mailing list would be great too. Basically I just dont need a whole effing shopping cart and 200 pages of code. If user registration and subscriptions are the base that I can get it down to, I'd be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a php based mailing list [PHPList](http://www.phplist.com/), but I recommend [Mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html), the de facto standard python powered mailing list program.

Comment: If you are going to use an application for commercial use, do check if the license for PHPList or mailman supports this.

Comment: I don't think these handle payment gateways :(